How to produce a shortest readable representation of numbers
What would be the closest format for printf, std::format  or std::ios_base formatters/manipulators to produce the most compact readable representation of numbers, limited (if possible) by amount of characters?
I need something more compact than C++ std suggests, for example:
With the requirement (as an example, as well): fit to 4 characters if possible and choose even shorter representation if all the information shown. Prefer more human-readable form (with "K/M" suffixes if the length is the same).



Value
Representation




1000
1K


1234
1.2K


244000
244K


3000000
3M


1.0e+9
1E+9


1.0e+10
1E10


0.001
1e-3


1.200
1.2


1.2345
1.23



(If anybody knows how to make this table here not so wide, please edit or let me know).
But what would be the best starting point?
I am looking at the std::setprecision and std::ios_base::setf, but it seems with my requirements of "shorter" and "K/M" suffixes it will take extra work here.
The goal is to set values on axis and grid steps of charts. It is always a shortage of space there.

Your requirements are probably too specific/unclear for anything built in, I would just write the formatting function myself

@EricJin, sure. I see that it is custom. The question is "what would be the best starting point?". Would you start with some existing formatting and manipulators? If so, what would you recommend?

@EricJin, as a second thought; isn't this a common task when implementing charts and other visual stuff with numbers where the space is quite limited? Wouldn't people like "1.5M" more than "1E+6" or quite long "1500000"? I mean, what makes my task so specific? Don't people draw charts?

The thing is we don't know if you want 150000 to be displayed as 150k, 1.5e5, how many sig figs, etc. I would just go old school and write my own function with something like if 1000 < number < 1000000 {format with k}, if 1000000 < number < 1000000000 {format with M}, if number is really large {format with scientific}. That way you also get to customize how you want different numbers displayed

@EricJin, on your example with 150000; just curious, if this is not obvious from the requirement? It is asking for the shortest readable form and the answer here is very straightforward in this terms: "150K" is shorter than "1.5e5". Anyway, I got the point and updated the requirement with "Prefer more human-readable form (with "K/M" suffixes if the length is the same)", although I understand that some people will start arguing about "more human-readable" which is a matter of habit. Anyway, just curios if this really makes the requirement "unclear".

@EricJin, and, getting back to "too specific", am I again the only person who needs short number marks for charts, etc. and want to have them human-friendly (like "5.1M" against this ugly "5.1e+06" or something like that)? Do people really prefer to count zeros and powers so much that they don't want to have in std some common abbreviations? The only answer I could figure out is that C++ is not UI-oriented and for calculations and data files this is not needed.

I mean it's not something that's "stl-worthy" IMO. Imagine how many things would be in it if there were. I would still suggest manually writing the formatter. It wouldn't take very long and you can customize
